# Calling getaddrinfo directly from Python: ai_addr is null pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, libc, getaddrinfo

I'm trying to call `getaddrinfo` from Python, through ctypes / libc, on Mac OS, in order to find the IP address of a domain.

The call *appears* to succeed: no error code is returned, and `ai_addrlen` is set to 28, which I understand is the appropriate length for an IPv6 address. However, `ai_addr` appears to be a null pointer, and I'm not sure how to begin to debug it.

How can I find the IP address of a domain using `libc.getaddrinfo` ?

```
from ctypes import (
    byref,
    c_char, c_char_p, c_int, c_size_t, c_void_p,
    CDLL,
    POINTER,
    pointer,
    Structure,
)

libc = CDLL(None)

class c_addrinfo(Structure):
    pass

c_addrinfo._fields_ = [
    ('ai_flags', c_int),
    ('ai_family', c_int),
    ('ai_socktype', c_int),
    ('ai_protocol', c_int),
    ('ai_addrlen', c_size_t),
    ('ai_addr', c_void_p),
    ('ai_canonname', c_char_p),
    ('ai_next', POINTER(c_addrinfo)),
]

c_addrinfo_p = POINTER(c_addrinfo)
result = c_addrinfo_p()
error = libc.getaddrinfo(
    c_char_p(b'www.google.com'),
    None,
    None,
    byref(result),
)

print(error)                          # 0
print(result.contents.ai_canonname)   # b'\x1c\x1e
print(result.contents.ai_addrlen)     # 28
print(bool(result.contents.ai_addr))  # False === null pointer

libc.freeaddrinfo(result)
```

Comment: Is there a reason `socket.getaddrinfo` won't work for you?

Comment: @zwol In terms of getting the IP address: none as far as I know. However, I am looking to get more familiarity with making syscalls from Python, and this seemed like reasonable place to start.

Comment: getaddrinfo is not a "syscall" in the sense that term is used by C programmers.  It's one of the more complicated routines in the C library and I do not think it is a good place to start with `ctypes`.  This doesn't make the question a bad one taken strictly on its own terms, though.

Comment: Addressing the question on its own terms, when I run this program, the output I get is `0`, `None`, `16`, and `True` (on four lines).  So I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: @zwol Ah understood about it not being a syscall. What os are you running on?

Comment: The above was Linux.  I just tried it on a NetBSD box (which is much more similar to MacOS) and there I get the same output you do, including the `b'\x1c\x1e'` for `ai_canonname` and 28 for `ai_addrlen`. Unfortunately I haven't the foggiest idea why it should do this, or why the behavior should vary between BSD and GNU C libraries.

Comment: At this point I must apologize for not being able to actually help, and leave this question for someone else.

Comment: @zwol Ah but thank you! Very good to know about the differences, even if so far _why_ there are differences isn’t known.

Comment: @zwol If you're interested, I think I've found the source of the difference https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584085/1319998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [linux man page for getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) the `addrinfo` struct which results form `getaddrinfo` are stored is defined as

```
struct addrinfo {
    int              ai_flags;
    int              ai_family;
    int              ai_socktype;
    int              ai_protocol;
    socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    char            *ai_canonname;
    struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};
```

and according to the [FreeBSD man page for getaddrinfo](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getaddrinfo&sektion=3) (or one of [Apple's man pages for getaddrinfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) which is similar), its `addrinfo` looks the same, assuming all the types match up.

```
struct addrinfo {
     int ai_flags;             /* input flags */
     int ai_family;            /* address family for socket */
     int ai_socktype;          /* socket type */
     int ai_protocol;          /* protocol for socket */
     socklen_t ai_addrlen;     /* length of socket-address */
     struct sockaddr *ai_addr; /* socket-address for socket */
     char *ai_canonname;       /* canonical name for service location */
     struct addrinfo *ai_next; /* pointer to next in list */
};
```

*However* looking in the [FreeBSD source](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/include/netdb.h#L135) (or [one of the open source Apple projects](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libinfo/Libinfo-278/lookup.subproj/netdb.h.auto.html) which is similar), we see a subtly different definition:

```
struct addrinfo {
    int ai_flags;             /* AI_PASSIVE, AI_CANONNAME, AI_NUMERICHOST */
    int ai_family;            /* AF_xxx */
    int ai_socktype;          /* SOCK_xxx */
    int ai_protocol;          /* 0 or IPPROTO_xxx for IPv4 and IPv6 */
    socklen_t ai_addrlen;     /* length of ai_addr */
    char *ai_canonname;       /* canonical name for hostname */
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr; /* binary address */
    struct addrinfo *ai_next; /* next structure in linked list */
};
```

It's very easy to miss, but `ai_canonname` and `ai_addr` *are the other way around to how they are documented*. This means that the Python ctypes definition, for Mac(/similar) should be

```
class c_addrinfo(Structure):
    pass

c_addrinfo._fields_ = [
    ('ai_flags', c_int),
    ('ai_family', c_int),
    ('ai_socktype', c_int),
    ('ai_protocol', c_int),
    ('ai_addrlen', c_size_t),
    ('ai_canonname', c_char_p),
    ('ai_addr', c_void_p),
    ('ai_next', POINTER(c_addrinfo)),
]
```

or one that works on both Mac and Linux (and with no comment on other platforms)

```
import platform

c_addrinfo._fields_ = [
    ('ai_flags', c_int),
    ('ai_family', c_int),
    ('ai_socktype', c_int),
    ('ai_protocol', c_int),
    ('ai_addrlen', c_size_t),
] + ([
    ('ai_canonname', c_char_p),
    ('ai_addr', c_void_p),
] if platform.system() == 'Darwin' else [
    ('ai_addr', c_void_p),
    ('ai_canonname', c_char_p),
]) + [
    ('ai_next', POINTER(c_addrinfo)),
]
```

And with these versions, on Mac, the pointer `ai_addr` is no longer null. You can also see an [early/experimental version that parses the addresses themselves that works in both Mac and Linux](https://gist.github.com/michalc/046dc425f4ec4bb0524d736c412421df).

Edit: it looks like the [documentation issue has already been reported to FreeBSD](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225880)

Comment: Nice catch!  That neatly explains both why `ai_addr` was coming out as NULL, and why `ai_canonname` appeared to be garbage -- it was interpreting the first few bytes of the address as a string! I can confirm that NetBSD uses the same ordering as Darwin and FreeBSD, and that its `getaddrinfo(3)` manpage has the same inconsistency.